# Conformal Mapping $w=z^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

I have to map $|argz≤\frac{π}{4}|$ under the transformation $w=z^2$ ,the answer mentioned is right side of $w$ plane how ever Iam getting $u≤\frac{π}{4}$ could someone help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use polar.  $z=re^{i\theta}\implies w=z^2=r^2e^{2i\theta}$.  Thus $|\operatorname{arg}z|\le\pi/4$ gets mapped to $|\operatorname{arg}z|\leπ/2$.

Comment: Could you pls show how $|argz<\frac{π}{4}|$ gets mapped to$|argz<\frac{π}{2}|$

Comment: As I tried to indicate, the argument, $\theta$, in $z=re^{i\theta}$, gets multiplied by $2$.